# Check for greatest common multiple in a range

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am supposed to be writing a program that takes two numbers and checks to see if they have a common multiple in the range of 1 - 1100000000, 1.1 billion. If there are many common multiples, I have to single out the greatest of these numbers.

The example gives us the numbers 2 and 3 and states that 1099999998 is the highest before breaching 1.1 billion.

My coding solutions, while workable, caused some other issues, so I need a purely mathematical solution. Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: If $n=\text{lcm}(a,b)$, then the desired result would be $\lfloor1.1\times10^9/n\rfloor\times n$. If it returns 0, there is no common multiple less than $1.1\times10^9$.

Comment: And lcm$(a,b)=ab/\gcd(a,b)$ is easily calculated using the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your responses!